# parse string to time

Tags: php

I am looking to extract the time out of this string

```
Tue, 13 Mar 2012 04:48:34 -0400
```

I know that strtotime may work but I am not sure of implemation on how to just get `04:48:34` out from that string

thanks

Comment: What if the timezone is something other than "-0400"? Do you really just want to ignore the timezone?

Comment: 99.999% of webdevelopers don't care about timezone (there's nothing about you Autolycus). They *may* care only if the website becomes international...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [date_parse](https://www.php.net/date_parse) which returns an array with the date/time parts as separate elements. You can then extract the time parts, e.g.

```
$dateString = 'Tue, 13 Mar 2012 04:48:34 -0400';
$dateParts = date_parse( $dateString );
$timeString = $dateParts['hour'] . ':' . $dateParts['minute'] . ':' . $dateParts['second'];
```

Or better, if you have PHP5.3, you can use the [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$dateString = 'Tue, 13 Mar 2012 04:48:34 -0400';
$date = new DateTime( $dateString );
echo $date->format( 'H:i:s' );
```

Comment: would you happen to know if using this class I can find the next closet hour. Like in this case it will be 5

Comment: @Autolycus Depends on what you mean by "next closest hour". It sounds like another question to me. Give it a go and post another question if you hit a problem.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there exist a concrete method that can do this for you, but off the top of my head:

```
echo date('H:m:s');
```

Comment: That will return the current hour:minutes:seconds, since you are not passing in a Unix Timestamp (the second parameter for date).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sscanf.php) function?

Here's the "home made" solution that works:

```
$r = sscanf ( 'Tue, 13 Mar 2012 04:48:34 -0400' , '%s %d %s %d %02d:%02d:%02d %d');
if (count($r)==7) {
  $hh = intval($r[4]);
  $mn = intval($r[5]);
  $ss = intval($r[6]);
  if (
    ($hh>=0) && ($hh<=23) &&
    ($mn>=0) && ($mn<=59) &&
    ($ss>=0) && ($ss<=59)
  ) { 
    /* Time is valid, use it


     */
  }
}
```